# Is it possible to retrieve the drawable name that's occupying an imageView that's using a random array

Tags: java, android

I have a educational kids game where the object is to match the image with the correct answer, 4 buttons provided for potential answers. The first part was to randomly fill the imageView with drawables that never repeat up to end of game. This part I have figured out and works. The part I'm having trouble with is dealing with the idea on how to compare what random image is in the imageView at that moment to 
1. Make sure one of the four options is a correct answer and 
2. To compare whatever is clicked to what is in the imageView at that time.

I tried imgView.getId(); , but it didn't work.

Array

```
private ArrayList<Integer> res1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
int arrPos = 0;
```

Method that randomizes

```
private void randomImage1() {
    Collections.shuffle(res1);
    imgView.setImageResource(res1.get(arrPos));
    arrPos = arrPos + 1;

}
```

onclick

```
        button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(counter <= 2){

                imgView.setImageResource(res1.get(arrPos));
            //randomImage1();
            counter = counter + 1;
            arrPos = arrPos+1;
            System.out.println(arrPos);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Integer.toString(counter) , 
                       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else if(counter == 3){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Integer.toString(counter) + "Game Over", 
                           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

My idea is to assign an id for each image + correct answer and maintain a list of available ids (with corresponding images and correct answers). So for your questions:

1. Make sure one of the four options is a correct answer

   Get a random id, get the corresponding image to display and corresponding correct answer to be one of the 4 options. Take the id out from the list, get 3 other options from the rest of the id and their corresponding answers.
2. To compare whatever is clicked to what is in the imageView at that time.

   When you display ImageView and options you can use `android:tag` to keep the ids of the correct answers and incorrect answers.
   Then in your code, use `getTag()` on the view to get the ids of the image and the chosen answer for comparison.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Set an id for each image and get the id of image on click. Maintain the HashMap for comparison between the image selected and its answers.